# PyYAML with Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyyaml

I've a problem using the *yaml* (PyYAML 3.11) library in Python 3.x. When I call `import yaml` I get the following error:

```
Python 3.4.3+ (default, Oct 14 2015, 16:03:50) 
[GCC 5.2.1 20151010] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import yaml
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/mlohr/python-libs/yaml/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from error import *
ImportError: No module named 'error'
```

`error` is a file located in the yaml directory, but the `__init__.py` from yaml does use absolute imports. I guess that's the problem, but I#'m not sure.

In http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation#Python3support is a short path about (supposed) Python 3 support, so I'm not sure if I'm using it the wrong way.

The same issue occurs (that's the way I found the problem) when using Python 3 with python scripts using yaml.

With Python  2.7 and 2.6 it works without problems.

Any idea/suggestion how to get that working?

Comment: How did you install PyYAML? pip? setup.py? tarball? Did you install it with sudo privileges?

Comment: Your traceback hints that you actually have an old version of PyYAML, because `from error import *` is not an absolute import (which as you say PyYAML 3.11 uses).

Comment: You installed with 2.x and got the 2.x version of the sources from PyYAML 3.11, if you install with 3.x you get different sources installed.

Comment: Thank you, that seems to be the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would seem that you're either using an old version of `PyYAML` after all or using a Python2 installation of `PyYAML` with Python3 as suggested in an [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36055462/2681632), because in your traceback we see

```
from error import *
```

which is not an absolute import. You should either upgrade, reinstall `PyYAML` with Python3 sources in your environment, or create a new environment for Python3 packages.

Comment: It is not an older version, it is the 2.x source of 3.11 that was already installed and re-used. See my answer for the links to the two different toplevel `__init__.py` files that are in PyYAML

Comment: @Anthon I'll be damned, that did not even cross my mind. Feel free to downvote this, or should I edit or remove.

Comment: Also: how braindead is that? Why not just merge the sources with compat helpers and future imports, as you've done.

Comment: I actually merged the PyYAML 2.x and 3.x sources as one of the first things I did for `ruamel.yaml` and I didn't realise this immediately  %-) . Your answer might still be correct (although with the long time nothing got changed/fixed in PyYAML it is unlikely that the OP has an older version. I am not going to downvote. If you want you can refer to my answer as a (more) likely cause for the OPs problem.

Comment: There is actually an open [PR for the merge](https://bitbucket.org/xi/pyyaml/pull-requests/6/merge-of-python2-and-python3-codebases) from me, but as there was no reaction to that, I just moved forward, not wanting to propose further changes to two source bases. That was the correct course of action IMHO, as PyYAML development seems to have stalled.

Comment: I feel you, it has been painful to get Py3 support merged to some projects.

Answer (score 3):

Your environment is polluted. If you create a (temporary) virtualenv this works without a problem:

```
$ mktmpenv -p /opt/python/3.4/bin/python
Running virtualenv with interpreter /opt/python/3.4/bin/python
Using base prefix '/opt/python/3.4'
New python executable in /home/venv/tmp-504ff2573d39ad0c/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
This is a temporary environment. It will be deleted when you run 'deactivate'.
(tmp-504ff2573d39ad0c) $ pip install pyyaml
Collecting pyyaml
Installing collected packages: pyyaml
Successfully installed pyyaml-3.11
(tmp-504ff2573d39ad0c) $ python
Python 3.4.3 (default, Jun  5 2015, 09:05:22) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import yaml
>>>
```

The most likely cause for this is that you are re-using YAML as installed for Python 2.X. The PyYAML sources are actually different for [2.x](https://bitbucket.org/xi/pyyaml/src/ddf211a41bb231c365fece5599b7e484e6dc33fc/lib/yaml/__init__.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default) and [3.x](https://bitbucket.org/xi/pyyaml/src/ddf211a41bb231c365fece5599b7e484e6dc33fc/lib3/yaml/__init__.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default) installs.

The easiest way around this is to install and use [ruamel.yaml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml) (disclaimer: I am the author of that package), which is an upgrade for PyYAML where the sources are once more recombined.